# How do i create a loop in jsx from a graphql query data?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Body: example of graphql query

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query servicesQuery {
      allFile{
        edges {
          node {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxHeight: 50, maxWidth: 50) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

I need to put all the images of this query in a `<img>` tag loop in jsx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [gatsby-image-plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/) from gatsby

```
import Img from "gatsby-image"
return (
 {data.allFile.edges.map(img => (
     <Img
         fluid={img.node.childImageSharp.fluid}
         alt="image"
     />
  ))}
)
```